# How to unpivot the following columns?

Tags: t-sql, unpivot

I have a table Tabel1 with columns id, data1, value1A, value1B, date2, value2A, value2B.

Data is like

```
id, data1,        value1A, value1B, date2,       value2A,    value2B
111, 01/01/1999,  10,      11,      05/05/2000   20,         22
222, 01/01/2005,  30,      32,      07/07/2007   44,         46
```

I want to get it arranged like the following:

```
id,  data,        value1, value2
111, 01/01/1999,  10,      11
111  05/05/2000   20,      22
222, 01/01/2005,  30,      32
222, 07/07/2007   44,      46
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by using `cross apply`:

```
declare @tbl as table   (id int,data1 date,data2 date,value1A int,value1B int,value2A int,value2B int)

insert into @tbl
values (111,'1999-01-01','2000-05-05',10,11,20,22),
       (222,'2005-01-01','2007-07-07',30,32,44,46)

select
    id
,   cp.*
from    @tbl
cross apply
(
values
    (data1,value1A,value1B),(data2,value2A,value2B)
)cp([data],value1,value2)
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=776988230484945b1126b96763b9acae)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `union all` operator:

```
--test dataset
declare @somedata as table
(
    id int,
    data1 date,
    value1A int,
    value1B int,
    data2 date,
    value2A int,
    value2B int
)
insert into @somedata
values (111, '1999-01-01', 10, 11, '2000-05-05', 20, 22),
       (222, '2005-01-01', 30, 32, '2007-07-07', 44, 46)

--query
select  c.id, 
        c.data, 
        c.value1, 
        c.value2
from (  select  id, 
                data1 as data, 
                value1A as value1, 
                value1B as value2
        from @somedata as a
        union all
        select  id, 
                data2, 
                value2A, 
                value2B
        from @somedata as b) as c
order by c.id, c.data
```

output:

[image]